# semantic ui - how to style table headings

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, jsx

So I have built a table in semantic-ui. very simple. however styles dont seem to apply to my table in certain aspects and i cant get the headings to map over the columns. see the below screenshot

[image]

the L column is fine but the others are a bit wonky and name is just well off. how can i adjust the styles so make this work?

I have tried to add a width to the div my table sits in but it just extends it without altering the table body or head

here is the code:

```
<div className="tableContainer">
        <h1> Table </h1>
        <table className="ui striped table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className="headings">Ranks</th>
              <th className="headings">Name</th>
              <th className="headings">P</th>
              <th className="headings">W</th>
              <th className="headings">L</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {this.props.players.sort(function(a, b) {
                return (a.rank) - (b.rank);
            }).map(function(player, index) {
            index +=1;
            return <tr key={index} className="table-rows">
                     <td className="stats">{player.rank}</td>
                     <td className="stats">{player.name}</td>
                     <td className="stats">{player.played}</td>
                     <td className="stats">{player.wins}</td>
                     <td className="stats">{player.losses}</td>
                   </tr>
          }, this)}
          </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide the relevant markup and css in order for people to troubleshoot it.

Comment: @RobertWade done

Comment: Need your CSS too (or a working fiddle).

Comment: @RobertWade i have no css, sorry. im using the css inherited from semantic ui

Comment: In order for people to help you here, you have to provide a working example of your issue or at bare minimum the code necessary to reproduce the problem.  You can't expect people to go out and piece together your problem based on screen snapshots and markup without CSS.  Obviously you have the CSS if you're using semantic ui.  Most likely you downloaded it or are linking to a cdn for it.  Gather the pieces of that CSS and provide it with your example.  Otherwise I'm afraid most people here are going to be unwilling to help you out.

Comment: I agree with Robert here.

From what I can see from your sample is that since it's a table it should all be aligned no matter the css. Try assembling a fiddle example with static data and css linked.

Comment: I have installed this dependency: `semantic-ui-css`. I'm not going to take screenshots of the console displaying my css. i was just wondering if on base level someone could see something wrong. because i have followed the docs to the law. and im not particularly looking for a solution but just a way of widening my table as I believe that will solve my problem.

Comment: @RobertWade genuinely have no css to show as it's all inherited from that dev-dep

Comment: I'm not trying to be argumentative and genuinely would like to help.  But if you've installed a dependency for semantic-ui via node, gulp or whatever then you have the CSS files in you application and could grab relevant styles from it and provide them.  If your HTML is accessing your CSS, then you also have the ability to access it and copy/paste from it to here to provide an example.

Comment: sure, same. but im not sure where the css lives? normally the html file would require it in but in this case because of the way semantic works it all gets bundled up in webpack I cant see it. there is genuinely nothing in my css except for one line making the top row gold. everything else is done by semantic, i assumed "magically" by the fact that im requiring it at the top and semantic recognising im using a table. 
 cant see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Reactjs, you should use Semantic-UI's reactjs package: [Semantic-UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction). In the `Table` section, you can see that certain properties are passed through props. You can set the column number with `columns` prop. And under the `Table.Header` tab, you can see that there's a `className` prop. You can use it to style your header. For reference, visit: [Semantic-UI React Table](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table).

Comment: To install the dependency, just do `npm install semantic-ui-react --save`.